# Unable to connect to the VM on port 22

Tags: google-compute-engine

I would like help in resolving the following issue...

"We are unable to connect to the VM on port 22. Learn more about possible causes of this issue."

After having stopped and restarted the VM because of the following issue below, the new issue above came up.

"Connection failed, An error occurred while communicating with the SSH server. Check the server and the network configuration"

I have tried the recommend ways of troubleshooting the issue via putty which did not work and the firewall seems okay.

Just wondering if they are any other suggestions of resolving this...

ADDITIONAL INFO AND UPDATES
-  Was following this tutorial(link below) to install NVM which caused the initial issue. I think I might have made changes to the user profile directory and bash files which is causing login issues.

https://github.com/creationix/nvm#install-script

- I was able to recreate the problem, using another instance. So the /usr/lib directory was deleted. Any possibility of reinstalling the library files?

Comment: Can you show us your firewall rules ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the /usr/lib directory is the directory where the libraries of all programs in linux are stored. I don't think you can do anything about it. The best solution is to attach the disk on another machine and extract the data  [link to the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/attach-disk)

Answer (score 0):

- Did you tried to ssh to your server using the [Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/compute/instances)?
  You just need to click on the button "SSH" on the right of your server's name.
- If you successfully accessed to the server, try the following command on your local machine:

  $ gcloud compute ssh [INSTANCE_NAME] --project [YOUR_PROJECT_ID] --zone [YOUR_ZONE]
- if you can't connect to your instance using gcloud compute ssh, you can enable the [serial port](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console#before-you-begin) and try to connect to your instance.

  $ gcloud compute connect-to-serial-port [INSTANCE_NAME] --project [YOUR_PROJECT_ID]
- If you can't connect to your instance, please share with us the Serial console output. In the Developers Console select your server and from your VM instance page go to the bottom where you can see a link "Serial console output".  Click on it.

Comment: Hi Miguel, thanks for you prompt response. Yes I tried all the above. Here is the output from the serial console..

Comment: Hi Miguel, thanks for your prompt response. So tried all of the above. Here is the serial output..
Failed to start Login Service.
See 'systemctl status systemd-logind.service' for details.
Failed to start System Logging Service.
See 'systemctl status rsyslog.service' for details.
Failed to start Apply the settings specified in cloud-config.
See 'systemctl status cloud-config.service' for details.
Failed to start Snappy daemon.
See 'systemctl status snapd.service' for details.
Started iSCSI initiator daemon (iscsid).
Started LSB: MD monitoring daemon.

Comment: I can see that the login service is failing to start. is the instance based on a [google image](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images)?.

Comment: you can create a bash script to reinstall the [packages of google](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/configuring-imported-images#install_guest_environment).

Comment: gcloud compute instances add-metadata example-instance \
    --metadata-from-file startup-script=path/to/file

#! /bin/bash
sudo su -
curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
DIST='stretch'
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud.list << EOM
deb http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt google-compute-engine-${DIST}-stable main
deb http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt google-cloud-packages-archive-keyring-${DIST} main
EOM
apt-get update
apt-get install -y google-cloud-packages-archive-keyring google-compute-engine python-google-compute-engine

Comment: Thank you Miguel for responding. I actually looked into this as another possible step i.e. start up scripts but unfortunately I am a novice at this, so wasn't quite sure the steps needed to do this. Please could you clarify the steps in order to do this? Thank you

Comment: Also would there any data loss by reinstalling these packages? Thanks

Comment: Yes the instance is based on a google image. Just tried running the script. Still the same error. Both via ssh and serial port.

Comment: UPDATE. I was able to recreate the problem, using another instance. So there /usr/lib directory was deleted. Is there a way to reinstalling those files using a script?

Comment: the /usr/lib directory is the directory where the libraries of all programs in linux are stored. I don't think you can do anything about it. The best solution is to attach the disk on another machine and extract the data [link to the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/attach-disk)

Comment: Thank you. We came to similar conclusion. Your suggestions were very helpful in diagnosing the cause of the problem.